# Reading data from Excel in selenium getting "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer":java.lang.module.ResolutionException:

Tags: java, excel, selenium, exception, apache-poi

Code :

```
package Selenium;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.NumberToTextConverter;

public class excelReader {

//Identify Testcases column by scanning the entire 1st row
//once column is identified then scan entire testcase column to identify purchase testcase row
//after you grab purchase testcase row = pull all the data of that row and feed into test

public static ArrayList<String> getData(String testcaseName) throws IOException
{
    // fileInputStream argument
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C://Users//Sivaranjani Gopal//Desktop//siva.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    int sheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();

    for (int i = 0; i < sheets; i++)
    {
        if (workbook.getSheetName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("testdata"))
        {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            // Identify Testcases column by scanning the entire 1st row
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();
            Row firstrow = rows.next();

            Iterator<Cell> ce = firstrow.cellIterator();//row is collection of cells
            int k = 0;
            int column = 0;

            while (ce.hasNext())
            {
                Cell value = ce.next();
 
                if (value.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("TestCases"))
                {
                    column = k;
                }

                k++;
            }

            System.out.println(column);
 
            // once column is identified then scan entire testcase column to identify purchase testcase row
            while (rows.hasNext())
            {
                Row r = rows.next();

                if (r.getCell(column).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(testcaseName))
                {
                    // after you grab purchase testcase row = pull all the data of that row and feed into test
                    Iterator<Cell> cv = r.cellIterator();

                    while (cv.hasNext())
                    {
                        Cell c = cv.next();

                        if (c.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING)
                        {
                            a.add(c.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            a.add(NumberToTextConverter.toText(c.getNumericCellValue()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getData("siva");
}
```

Could some one help on the error?

I am getting the below exception when I run the code:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules jaxb.impl and jaxb.core export package com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation to module poi

Need help on the above exception.

Comment: Use the classpath not the modulepath for your dependencies?

Comment: thanks for the fix  @Gagravarr  it worked. could you tell me what is the difference between classpath and module path

Comment: Now unable to get the array list elements being printed. can some help on it? it is returning "a", but no output.